# Is there an exam like TOEFL for English, but for Italian that I can take online?

Tags: cefr, certifications, italian

The thing is I am asked to pass a 6-credit Italian exam this semester. I am currently out of Italy and can not take the university exam which is held in person. I have practiced my Italian and I am good enough for A2. The university will conduct A2 level proficiency. I explained to the university my situation and they told me they will waive the course if I have CEFR approved certificate for A2.

My question is, is there an online examination like TOEFL or Duolingo type that allows me to take the exam of A2 proficiency remotely? I am trying to avoid going to Italy just for the sake of this course only if I can.

Comment: https://www.interno.gov.it/it/temi/immigrazione-e-asilo/modalita-dingresso/test-conoscenza-lingua-italiana Il cittadino straniero che vive legalmente in Italia da più di 5 anni e intende chiedere il permesso CE per soggiornanti di lungo periodo (articolo 9 testo unico immigrazione) deve sostenere e superare il test di conoscenza della lingua italiana, disciplinato dal decreto del ministro dell'interno 4 giugno 2010.

Comment: A response would be nice.